# Assigning Character Limit to a Specific UITextField

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

The following code works but applies to all TextFields. How can I limit it to one specific TextField?

**Code:**

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

    let currentCharacterCount = (textField.text?.characters.count) ?? 0
    if (range.length + range.location > currentCharacterCount){
        return false
    }
    let newLength = currentCharacterCount + string.characters.count - range.length
    return newLength <= 9
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you have two textFields and your controller is a delegate of both.

```
  @IBOutlet var aMagesticTextField: UITextField!
  @IBOutlet var anotherMagesticTextField: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        aMagesticTextField.delegate = self
        anotherMagesticTextField.delegate = self
    }
```

In shouldChangeCharactersIn, check the textField parameter against your known text fields.

```
        if textField == aMagesticTextField {
            //It's aMagesticTextField
        }
        else {
            //It's anotherMagesticTextField
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

### Two Options

1) Implement the code you referenced in the `UITextFieldDelegate` implementation for only that one TextField. I strongly prefer this option.

2) Conditionally check for something that uniquely identifies the TextField you are interested in such as its `tag` property. Only run the character count check for that TextField. Otherwise, default to true.

I never use the tag property for identifying a UI element and don't suggest it. However, I see it used often.

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

    // Set textField tag to 9 if you want pass this guard
    guard textField.tag == 9 else {
        return true
    }

    let currentCharacterCount = (textField.text?.characters.count) ?? 0
    if (range.length + range.location > currentCharacterCount){
        return false
    }
    let newLength = currentCharacterCount + string.characters.count - range.length
    return newLength <= 9
}
```

Comment: THANKS THIS IS EXACTLY WHAT I NEED